# Find all solutions of equation $x^{23}=5$ in $\Bbb Z_{23}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I just found that $5$ is a solution by using Fermat's theorem.

But, I am not sure whether there are more solutions and how I could find them...

Comment: why is this tagged group theory when you are actually working in a field?

Comment: does that mean that 5 is only solution?

Comment: 5 is indeed the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Fermat's theorem tells you what $x^{23}\pmod{23}$ is $x$ for any $x \ne 5$ as well.

Comment: x^23 = x (mod 23) right? it seems then that 5 is only solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find more than one solution in general when you are dealing with $Z_p$ and so $x^{23} \equiv 5 \pmod {23}$ and using fermats like u said u know that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ and so $$5^{23} \equiv 5 \pmod {23}$$

Note that this is a unique soltion because if You there was another $x$ to be found then $$x \equiv 5 \pmod {23}$$ One can see that this never happens except for $x =[5],[28],[51],.... etc$ which is basically the equivalence class $[5]$